# Can an excel VSTO add-in be compatible with excel 2007 and 2010?

Tags: excel, vsto

Is it possible to develop an excel add-in using VSTO that can be deployed to both excel 2007 and 2010?

Any links to a detailed resource on this topic would also be appreciated - I can't seem to find anything on google that specifically addresses this question.

I am developing a C# excel add-in using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I already [answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966546) for Word, but it also applies to Excel:

If you want to deploy to Office 2010 AND 2007, you have to add references to the **v12.0** assemblies (*Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel* and *Office*).

Now there is still the problem that your addin will require the 2007 PIA, but they won't install if you only have Office 2010 on the target machine (because they have Office 2007 as a prerequisite).
To solve this you have to set **Embed Interop Assemblies = true** for those two dlls (in the reference properties) and use `dynamic` for the types you can't directly reference anymore.

This causes some "weirdness" with Intellisense not finding methods etc., but it should not be a big problem -at least now PIA are not required anymore and your addin will deploy on both 2007 and 2010 (you'll have to take care of the installer as well, but that is a whole other story).

It's a bit of a mess, but if you are working with VSTO I suppose you are used to this kind of stuff :-)

Comment: Thanks your response, this will be really helpful in getting started.

Comment: Hi. i am facing same problem. but i do not find "Embed Interop Assemblies" property in property windows. please suggest.

Comment: @Mitesh Khatri I think he meant `Embed Interop Types` and needed to set it to `true`